# How to convert variance of lnRR into percentage?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

Currently, I'm working on meta-analysis using the log-response ratio (`lnRR`) as my effect size. As indicated in Pustejovsky (2017), one can convert `lnRR` into percentage change for intuitive interpretation as follows:

```
percent change = 100% * [exp(lnRR)-1]
```

My question is: is that possible to convert the corresponding variance of `lnRR` into an equivalence percentage? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you actually need the variance or are you just trying to convert confidence intervals?

Comment: Indeed, I need the variance.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the variance to calculate the confidence intervals (which presumably is an output in your meta-anaylsis), these could then be converted with the same formula above - e.g. your result might look like: 5% (1  to 9%)